# Show that if $\text{int}(E) = \text{int}(F) = ∅$ and $E$ is closed, then $\text{int}(E\cup F) = \emptyset $.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have the following doubt, they ask me the following:

Let $(X, d)$ a metric space and $E, F \subseteq X$. Show that if $\mathrm{int}(E) = \text{int}(F) = ∅$ and $E$ is closed, then $\text{int}(E\cup F) = \emptyset $.

I know that $x \in A$ is interior if there exists an $ r>0$ such that $B_r(x) \subset A$, but I cannot think how to start.

I appreciate your time reading this.

Comment: If $B_r(x) \subset E \cup F$ then $B_r(x) \setminus E$ is an open subset of $F$. What can you conclude from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $B$ is any open ball then $B$ is not contained in $E$. Take some $x \in B \setminus E$. There is a smaller open ball $B’ \subset B$ around $x$ that does not intersect $E$ (since $E$ is closed). But also $B’$ is not contained in $F$. So there is a point in $B’$ that is not in $E\cup F$.